# Jquery selector problem about "+"

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Today I found a strange jquery selector in the following code:

```
$(this).find("+div.parent").hide();
```

I've searched this in Jquery API and only found what `pre_element+next_element` means.What does the  `+` do in the code?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a typo but I look forward to hearing other opinions.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario,no it's not.Because if I remove this `+` the script will not work as expected.

Comment: Can you post the lines above and below the code you just posted?

Comment: @Salman A,the whole code block is `$("p").click( function(){
  $(this).find("+div.parent").hide();
 });`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the selector + matches the element that follows the previous one

for example if you want to matches all the `div`s that are after bold text you can use this selector:

```
$("b+div")
```

so if `$(this)` is reference to `<b>`:

```
$(this).find('+div.parent')
```

will match all the `div` with class `parent` that are immediately after `<b>`

Comment: The important point here is that `.find()` makes the selector relative to the DOM element that's being wrapped by jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

the `+` is an [Adjacent Sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

it will select the immediate sibling of the  `this`, it is equivalent to [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(this).find("+div.parent").hide();
```

is the same as

```
$(this).next("div.parent").hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

It'll find the `div` with the class `parent` adjacent to whatever `$(this)` is.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/prbRA/1/

Comment: This surprises me. Normally, the `find()` method returns/searches within the descendants of the element.

Comment: @Salman: Not if you look from a CSS point of view :). Try to turn the jQuery object to a CSS rule(let `$(this)` be a `h1`): `$(this).find('+p')`, `h1+p` would be the equivalent CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Find all the div with class parent which are immediately after the selected element $(this)